# How to convert a pdf file (composed of different images) to list of images in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am developeing a **PDF converter flutter app** it converts images into pdf file. I want to expand it so that it should take pdf file and convert it into list of images so that i can rearrange order of images or remove a specific image form pdf. How can i solve this issue.I tried multiple packages but didn't find a solution.
Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

I am developeing a PDF converter flutter app it converts images into pdf file. I want to expand it so that it should take pdf file and convert it into list of images so that i can rearrange order of images or remove a specific image form pdf. How can i solve this issue.I tried multiple packages but didn't find a solution. Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PDFTron SDK package.

```
 pdftron_flutter: ^0.5.0
```

or import this:

```
import 'package:pdftron_flutter/pdftron_flutter.dart';
import 'package:pdftron/pdftron.dart';
```

Initialize first:

```
await PDFNet.initialize();
```

methhods:

```
var pdfDoc = await PDFDoc.fromFilePath(filePath);
var page = await pdfDoc.getPage(pageNumber);
var resources = await page.getResources();
var image = await resources.getImage(imageName);
var imageData = await image.getImageData();
```

convert the image data to a flutter using `Image.memory`

```
var imageWidget = Image.memory(imageData);
```